# How do you Publish a Xamarin.Android App that's Obfuscated with ConfuserEx?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, obfuscation

I've created an Android app using Xamarin.Forms PCL and now I want to protect it before I release it.  I'm using ConfuserEx, although I've also tried .NET Reactor and had the same issue.

The problem I've run into is not with the obfuscator itself, it correctly does what it needs to do to my AppName.dll file, putting my obfuscated dll into the folder `$(SolutionDir)AppName\AppName.Droid\bin\Confused\AppName.dll`.  However, when I go to publish my app via AdHoc in VisualStudio 15, it publishes the apk with the non-obfuscated dll so I am easily able to reverse engineer the app on my own and see all my original code.

Here is my current setup:

- I created the ConfuserEx file called `NormalObfuscate.crproj` and put
  it in the folder with my solution.
- In the properties of my Android project, under the build events, I put the following post-build event:

> if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" "$(SolutionDir)ConfuserEx\Code\Confuser.CLI.exe" "$(SolutionDir)NormalObfuscate.crproj"
>
> if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" xcopy /Y "$(SolutionDir)AppName\AppName.Droid\bin\Confused\AppName.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\AppName\AppName.Droid\bin\Release\AppName.dll"
>
> if /I "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" xcopy /Y "$(SolutionDir)AppName\AppName.Droid\bin\Confused\AppName.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\AppName\AppName.Droid\obj\Release\linksrc\AppName.dll"

- I rebuilt the solution
- I archived the project and published it by clicking distribute and then signing the apk.

After all of this, I was able to unload the apk and the obfuscated dll wasn't in there, even though it's in my bin\Release folder.  Does anyone know how to get the archive manager to use the obfuscated dll when compressing and publishing the app?

Comment: Don't use the archive manager. Use `msbuild` and add a `<AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>true</AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>` to your `.csproj`. Otherwise the archive manager is just going to run it's normal configurations and ignore yours.

Comment: Will that sign my apk too?

Comment: Yes it should be equivalent to `/t:SignAndroidPackage`

Comment: I added your line to my project file after the line: `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">`.  It successfully created the signed apk file, but it still had the unobfuscated code.  Did I put it in the wrong spot?

Comment: You will need to ensure that these obfuscation tasks happen during build. They have to weave in the msbuild process to do this.

Comment: Okay, I'm attempting to run the obfuscation as a pre-build event instead of post-build.  Out of curiosity, when I've published before using the archive manager, I've needed to type in a password for my alias to sign the apk.  With this way, I haven't had to do that.   Does that matter at all when I go to publish in the Google Play Store?

Comment: So the command to obfuscate the code must be in the post build event in order to get the correct files to obfuscate.  Is there a way to specify for the AndroidBuildApplicationPackage to create the apk after the build is finished?   Otherwise, this won't work for me either.

Comment: The APK is typically a product AFTER a build. I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure how the whole flow works.  Right now I have the commands in the post build that obfuscate my dll and then copies it to my Release folder.  However, when I take apart the apk that is generated after the build, it is using the dll that isn't obfuscated.  I think that it is creating the apk before my post build commands are run, and therefore the obfuscated code isn't included.

Comment: I would highly recommend using https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog to ensure you are running the obfuscation after the Build task prior to the APK packaging task.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jon, I was able to get it to work by adding your line and then creating a batch script like the one [here] (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24396/obfuscation-and-manually-sign-an-apk).  This successfully assembled the apk with the obfuscated dlls.

Comment: @cvanbeek, will you post your bat file or more details on how you accomplished this?  We are at the exact same point and haven't been able to figure out how to get the obfuscated DLL's in the apk automatically.  We are using VS 2017.

Comment: I'll type what I did as an answer in a couple minutes.  I'm still using VS '15 though so I don't know if something might be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work in a more roundabout way.

First, in your project file for your App.Droid, under `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">` add `<AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>true</AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>`.  This will generate an unsigned APK when you rebuild your project.

Also in the project file add to the project the following lines:

```
<Target Name="Obfuscate" AfterTargets="_CopyIntermediateAssemblies" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="ObfuscateRelease.bat" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)" />
</Target>
```

This will run a bat file during the build process called `ObfuscateRelease.bat` that you must place in your main solution folder.

My `ObfuscateRelease.bat` file looks like this:

```
echo running ObfuscateRelease.bat
:: Call Confuser ex to obfuscate your project
START /WAIT "Obfuscating App.dll" "<Path to Confuser>\ConfuserEx\Code\Confuser.CLI.exe" "<Path to Confuser Ex file>\NormalObfuscate.crproj"
:: copy confused files into the release folders so it is packaged into the app
echo starting to copy
copy "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\bin\Confused\App.dll" "<Path to App>\App\App\App.Droid\bin\Release"
copy "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\bin\Confused\App.dll" "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\obj\Release\linksrc"
copy "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\bin\Confused\App.Droid.dll" "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\bin\Release"
copy "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\bin\Confused\App.Droid.dll" "<Path to App>\App\App.Droid\obj\Release\linksrc"
echo finished copying
echo finished ObfuscateRelease.bat
```

Then rebuild your project.  You should see the echoed lines in your build output.  Once the build is finished you will have a signed (With a debugging alias) and unsigned version of the app. You can then [sign the app manually](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/).  (I made another bat file to more easily execute the steps in doing this.)

Comment: thx for pointing me to the right direction. but i still have an error left. "System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid DOS signature". Does this method still work with latest version of xamarin?